# How to save map tiles locally in angular

Tags: angularjs

I was just going through this angular openlayers example **[HERE](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/022-center-autodiscover-example.html)** , and i wanted to know , how can i save the map tiles locally ? , i mean using localstorage , so that when the map is loaded the secound time around the tiles are loaded from the users device rather than fetching it over from the internet.

The angular code used in the above example can be seen below:

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['openlayers-directive']);
        app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                    lat: 0,
                    lon: 0,
                    autodiscover: true
                }
            });
       }]);
```

Well, can somebody tell me how can i save the map tiles locally ?

Thank you.

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular. You need to figure that out within the map API and quite honestly I doubt you realize all that is involved to get all the different scales

Comment: ` I doubt you realize all that is involved to get all the different scales` ... did't quite understand what u meant .

Comment: do some research into this then and figure out how map tiles work